# Parsing specific field in XML file in Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have an xml file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<feed xml:base="http://data.treasury.gov:8001/Feed.svc/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text">DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData</title>
  <id>http://data.treasury.gov:8001/feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData</id>
  <updated>2015-08-30T15:17:09Z</updated>
  <link rel="self" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData" />
  <entry>
    <id>http://data.treasury.gov:8001/Feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(6404)</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2015-08-30T15:17:09Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(6404)" />
    <category term="TreasuryDataWarehouseModel.DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">6404</d:Id>
        <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2015-08-03T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
        <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">0.03</d:BC_1MONTH>
        <d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">0.08</d:BC_3MONTH>
        <d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">0.17</d:BC_6MONTH>
        <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">0.33</d:BC_1YEAR>
        <d:BC_2YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">0.68</d:BC_2YEAR>
        <d:BC_3YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">0.99</d:BC_3YEAR>
        <d:BC_5YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.52</d:BC_5YEAR>
        <d:BC_7YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.89</d:BC_7YEAR>
        <d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.16</d:BC_10YEAR>
        <d:BC_20YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.55</d:BC_20YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.86</d:BC_30YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY m:type="Edm.Double">2.86</d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>http://data.treasury.gov:8001/Feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(6405)</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2015-08-30T15:17:09Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(6405)" />
    <category term="TreasuryDataWarehouseModel.DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">6405</d:Id>
        <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2015-08-04T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
        <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">0.05</d:BC_1MONTH>
        <d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">0.08</d:BC_3MONTH>
        <d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">0.18</d:BC_6MONTH>
        <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">0.37</d:BC_1YEAR>
        <d:BC_2YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">0.74</d:BC_2YEAR>
        <d:BC_3YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.08</d:BC_3YEAR>
        <d:BC_5YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.6</d:BC_5YEAR>
        <d:BC_7YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.97</d:BC_7YEAR>
        <d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.23</d:BC_10YEAR>
        <d:BC_20YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.59</d:BC_20YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.9</d:BC_30YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY m:type="Edm.Double">2.9</d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

How can I parse out the '2.16' for 'BC_10YEAR'? I've been looking at other examples with ElementTree and lxml and I just can't seem to match up the xml format in those examples with that of my file.

The last thing I've tried was:

```
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.parse(yield_xml)
memoryElem = doc.find('content')
print memoryElem.text        # element text
print memoryElem.get('type') # attribute
```

I get an error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try built-in split method:

```
>>>[data.split('>')[1].split('<')[0] for data in str(xml_file).split('<d:') if 'BC_10YEAR' in data][0]
'2.16'
```

Comment: I tried 'with open('test.xml', 'rb') as xml_file:
    [data.split('>')[1].split('<')[0] for data in str(xml_file).split('<d:') if 'BC_10YEAR' in data][0]' but I get "IndexError: list index out of range" error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It means you test.xml file object differs from example above.

Comment: That's strange, I'm pretty sure my file has exactly what I pasted above. Anyway, I modified to this to get it to work:`with open(yield_xml, 'rb') as yield_file:
        for line in yield_file:
            if 'BC_10YEAR' in line:
                cur_yield = float(line.split('>')[1].split('<')[0])
                break`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use `lxml`'s `xpath()` method which provide better XPath expression support :

```
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.parse(yield_xml)

#register prefixes to be used in xpath
ns = {"foo": "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
      "d": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices",
      "m": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"}

#select element <d:BC_10YEAR>, and convert the value to number
result = doc.xpath("number(//foo:content/m:properties/d:BC_10YEAR)", namespaces=ns)

#print the result
print(result)
print(type(result))
```

**output :**

```
2.16
<type 'float'>
```

In case you wonder why `foo:content` instead of just `foo` in the xpath expression above, that's because `content` inherits default namespace from the root element, implicitly. And the default namespace uri is mapped to prefix `foo` in the above code; related question : [parsing xml containing default namespace to get an element value using lxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31177707/parsing-xml-to-get-element-value-using-lxml/31178720#31178720)

Comment: Thanks the code works. Unfortunately my knowledge of xml is very limited so I could not understand much of what you said. I do have a question though: how does the code differentiate between the two 'BC_10YEAR' values in the xml file? The first one is 2.16 but there is another one that's 2.23.

Comment: The code will return the first only. Getting the the other one, or all `BC_10YEAR` is perfectly possible with a little change in the xpath argument